# How do I ask 'what to fill in blank'?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

As the following sentence, Is this phrase correct: 'to fill in blank'?

For example: "But I'm not sure about to fill in blank at agency owner agreement document"

I just want to ask someone what I should put in the blank in a document. How could I say this? Does make it sense? I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I do not understand what that sentence is trying to say. I expect "about to [verb]" to mean "very soon" ("I am *about to* leave"), but I can't make sense of it following "not sure". Also, I think "at agency owner agreement document" is missing an article -- perhaps it should be "at *the* agency owner agreement document"? You can't fill in a blank *at* anything, though. (Maybe if I understood your meaning more clearly, I could make a better suggestion. Are you filling in a blank space that is *on* the document?)

Comment: I just want to ask someone what am I fill in the blank in document. then how could I say to someone to ask for hint? does make it sense?

Comment: Are you asking about all of the blanks in an "agency owner agreement" document, or are you asking about one specific blank in the document that is labeled "agency owner agreement"? After reading Aaron's answer, now I'm not sure I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm not sure about to fill in blank at agency owner agreement document.

I think that your example sentence is close enough that we can fix it up before I tell you how I would say it.

You are missing something before "to fill" to be the subject of the infinitive clause and you should put a determiner in front of "blank", like "the" or "this" if you are talking about a specific blank.

> But I'm not sure about _____ to fill in **the** blank at agency owner agreement document.

You could say:

*I'm not sure about **how** to fill in the blank at agency owner agreement document.*
*I'm not sure about **what** to fill in the blank at agency owner agreement document.*

I would probably express the idea like this:

*I'm not sure what I should put in the blank at "Agency Owner Agreement Document".*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to say is "But I'm not sure about **how** to fill in the blanks on the agency owner agreement document."  **How to X** means the method of accomplishing X.

You could also ask, "What do I need to write in the blanks on the document?"